# Problema con booleano en setInterval - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

Tengo un booleano llamado `isFilter` en el cuál cuando esta en true hace un función y si no la otra función.
Esto tengo en el created para que cada 30 segundos vuelva ejecutar la función:

```
created() {
  this.load();
  setInterval(() => {
    if (this.isFilter) {
      this.filterVehicle();
    } else {
      this.load();
    }
  }, 30000);
},
```

Cuando activo el isFilter a true en un button o sea :

```
this.isFilter = true;
```

Si llama a la función en este caso `this.filterVehicle();`, todo bien pero el problema esta cuando pasan los 30 segundos y vuelve a ejecutar en ese entonces ejecuta la función: `this.load();` 
No se porque pasa eso ya que se supone que el estado sigue en **True** y cada vez que recarga debería pasar por la condición verdad?
Me esta faltando algo? ya que siempre deberia recargar manteniendo el estado del booleano para saber que función ejecutar.

** UPDATE: **

```
data() {
  return {
    isFilter: false,
  };
},
```

El error esta en esta parte:

```
methods: {
  filterVehicle() {
    if (!this.isFilter) {
      this.isFilter = true;

    } else {
      this.isFilter = false;
      this.load();
    }
  },
}
```

y el boton donde mando a llamar a la función **filterVehicle**

```
 <button class="button" :class="isFilter ? 'is-danger': 'is-primary'" @click="filterVehicle">
 <span v-if="isFilter" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-cancel"></i></span>
 <span v-else class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
 </button>
```

En donde cuando das click en el boton de filtrar cambia su estado a true y cambia el icono por una **X** entonces al yo dar click en la **X** quita el filtro esto funciona pero el problema que tengo es como manejar esos estados con el  **setInterval** ya que cuando actualiza este mismo, vuelve ejecutar la función y como el estado esta ahora en true pasa a traer el **LOAD** de que manera podría hacer lo mismo sin perder el filtro al ejecutar la función nuevamente con el **setInterval**??

Comment: Sube todo el codigo de esa vista a simple vista con lo que tenemos no podemos verificar que funciona o no.

Comment: En 1 hora subo un resumen donde están los methods y el data

Comment: actualice la pregunta

Comment: Yo mi respuesta, debes siempre subir el codigo de tu vista para entender bien cual es el problema. un saludo

Comment: si ya actualice la pregunta con el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno no me gusta la forma en la que la resolví pero de esta manera esta funcionando:

primero tuve que crear 2 funciones tanto para filtrar y otra para remover:

```
methods: {
  filterVehicle() {
    this.isFilter = true;
  },
  removeVehicle() {
    this.load();
    this.isFilter = false;
  },
}
```

y simplemente en mi vista simplemente jugue con el booleano y los **v-if** de vue:

```
<button v-if="!isFilter" class="button is-primary" @click="filterVehicle">
 <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
</button>
<button v-else class="button is-danger" @click="removeFilter">
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-cancel"></i></span>
</button>
```

De esta manera si funciona pero si hay otras ideas sería mejor :D

Answer (score -1):

**Debes cambiar esta linea de codigo:**

```
data() {
  return {
    isFilter: false,
  };
},
```

**Por esta:**

```
data: {
    isFilter: false
},
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero la pregunta era porque cambia el estado de true a false cuando actualiza el setinterval no de como poner las cosas en vuejs

Comment: La respuesta es que no estas poniendo los metodos y las propiedades donde deberian de ir........realmente en tu aplicacion no esta cambiando nada, al no definir los metodos/propiedades de la vist  donde deberian de ir this.isFilter nunca te devolverá true. Agregare este comentario a mi respuesta debido a que al parecer no entendiste.

Comment: Si te entiendo pero eso no es problema por eso no he puesto los métodos

Comment: entonces debes publicarlo porque fijate en mi ejemplo que si funciona